# Configure foreman to restart processes

Tags: foreman

Is it possible to configure [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to restart processes when they exit?  The default behaviour seems to be to kill all services if one exits.

Comment: you can try god gem instead of foreman

Answer (score 0):

You can use upstart with foreman to restart a killed or crashed process. It's explained well here: http://michael.vanrooijen.io/articles/2011/06/08-managing-and-monitoring-your-ruby-application-with-foreman-and-upstart/